# Unable to downgrade Angular from version 6 to 5

Tags: angular, angular5, rollback, downgrade, angular6

Recently (May 2018) newer stable version of angular has been released.
I have migrated succesfully from version 5 to 6.

But for some reason I wanted to rollback to version 5. I have tried following commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

it uninstalled the latest version of angular-6.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then installed

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4
```

But it gave this error
[image]

**node version**: 8.10.0

**npm version**: 6.0.0

Comment: Try and see if updating to the most recent release of npm solves the issue: `npm install -g npm@latest`

Comment: `npm ` version please, you have mentioned your node version. what does  `npm -v` shows?

Comment: @Vikas check last line of question

Comment: @eirenaios the latest version of `npm` is v6.0.1 how could you it be 8.10.0 it's your node version you `npm` version must be 5.6.0

Comment: @Vikas ooops right, npm version is 6.0.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to update npm...please refer to screenshot...I've sucessfully downgraded angular 6 to angular 5...
[image: downgrade from angular 6 to angular 5]

Comment: thanks it would be great if you write down all the commands that will help other users easily followup

Answer (score 15):

Same as the other answer, but this time only commands instead of a difficult to follow screenshot

I wanted to downgrade from 7.0.2 to 6.2.5

```
ng --version

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.5
ng --version
```

Answer (score 2):

run

`npm i npm@latest -g`

to update node package manager. then run again

`npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7`

Comment: I have problem with this either installing 1.7.4 or 6.2.5 it stays with angular 7.2.6. node:v8.11.3 npm:6.8.0. I am trying to downgrade angular7 to 6 but without success.

Answer (score 1):

First run these three commands to check which version is installed currently:

```
node -v
npm -v
ng --version
```

Then to uninstall the cli:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

To clean cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then install the version that you want `(X.X.X)`:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.5
```

To check the successfull update:

```
ng --version
```