# how to downgrade Angular from version 6 to 5

Tags: angular

i installed latest version of angular cli.

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
it uninstalled the latest version of angular-6.

npm cache clean --force
and then installed

npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4
But it gave  error

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the global version of Angular to 6. You can downgrade the Local version specific to your project to 1.x. ng command will pick the local setting instead of global.

You can refer this. [Unable to downgrade Angular from version 6 to 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268300/unable-to-downgrade-angular-from-version-6-to-5)