# How to downgrade from angular 11 to angular 9?

Tags: angular

With reference to [Unable to downgrade Angular from version 6 to 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268300/unable-to-downgrade-angular-from-version-6-to-5)

I tried using the same method `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
`npm cache clean --force`
`npm install -g @angular/cli@9.0.0`

I want to downgrade my current version of angular 11 to angular 9 however when I run `ng --version` I am still on angular 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@9.x.x
```

If you are thrown npm error, try updating npm before installing:

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to downgrade from 12 to 11.. however, only CLI does downgrade and not angular itself.. and I get the error when trying to run serve: `This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^11.0.0-next || >=11.0.0 <12.0.0,
but Angular version 12.0.0 was found instead.`

Comment: @FisnikTahiri Try downgrading the versions in your package.json