# Issue in angular updating version 12 to 13 in angular core

Tags: angular, package, angular12, angular13

**export 'ɵcoerceToBoolean' (imported as 'ɵcoerceToBoolean') was not found in '@angular/core'**

When i tried to update the project from angular 12 to 13,I got this error on the terminal.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Probably an issue of mixed versions from upgrade. Remove local version of folder `node_modules` and remove `package-lock.json` and reinstall using `npm i`. If that does not resolve your issue then follow the steps again using upgrade guide: https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=12.0-13.0

Comment: I tried removing / renaming `node_modules` first but got the same error. The additional step of removing `package-lock.json` and then running updates ended up upgrading my package.json to version 14 (which is currently prerelease and not what I want!). So then I deleted again, manually set the version to 13.4 and eventually got it working.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895057/how-to-downgrade-from-angular-11-to-angular-9